# Create paragraphs with dynamic ID and value from inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dynamic

I'm creating two paragraphs from two inputs but I can't put the content from the input into the paragraph.

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<form id="ip-form" class="custom-form wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control custom-input-form" id="name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="number" class="form-control my-ip" id="number" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-gray no-side-margin float-right" id="add-new">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6" id="new-names">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6" id="new-numbers">
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var countName = 0;
var countNumber = 0;

$('#add-new').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#new-names').append('<p id="new-name-'+countName+'"></p>');
    countName++;
    $('#new-numbers').append('<p id="new-number-'+countNumber+'"></p>');
    countNumber++;

  $('#"new-name'+countName+'"').text($('#name').val()); 
  $('#"new-number'+countNumber+'"').text($('#number').val());

});
```

I also created on simple Codepen with the code: https://codepen.io/fabiozanchi/pen/PJyeap

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, the construction `$('#"new-name'+countName+'"')` is broken, use `$('#new-name'+countName)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/phatison/pen/yzRjwQ)

Here is what I have done:

1. Fixed some syntax on lines 12 and 13.

ORIGINAL

```
$('#"new-name'+countName+'"').text($('#name').val()); 
$('#"new-number'+countNumber+'"').text($('#number').val());
```

NEW

```
$('#new-name'+countName).text($('#name').val()); 
$('#new-number'+countNumber).text($('#number').val());
```

2. I added `'+$('#name').val()+'` to line 7 and `'+$('#number').val()+'` to line 9, between the p tags.
3. I also changed the placeholder text of your number field. All seems to work fine.

**Notes**

Aside from some syntax errors, I didn't notice any major issues.

**New Code**

HTML

```
<form id="ip-form" class="custom-form wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control custom-input-form" id="name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="number" class="form-control my-ip" id="number" placeholder="Number">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-gray no-side-margin float-right" id="add-new">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6" id="new-names">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6" id="new-numbers">
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var countName = 0;
var countNumber = 0;

$('#add-new').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $('#new-names').append('<p id="new-name-'+countName+'">'+$('#name').val()+'</p>');
    countName++;
    $('#new-numbers').append('<p id="new-number-'+countNumber+'">'+$('#number').val()+'</p>');
    countNumber++;

  $('#new-name'+countName).text($('#name').val()); 
  $('#new-number'+countNumber).text($('#number').val());

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Most certainly! Glad I could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
var countName = 0;
var countNumber = 0;

$('#add-new').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#new-names').append('<p id="new-name-' + (countName++) + '">' + $('#name').val() + '</p>');
    $('#new-numbers').append('<p id="new-number-' + (countNumber++) + '">' + $('#number').val() + '</p>');
});
```

Try to make as minimal interactions with DOM as possible. Two `.append` and two `.val` calls are enough here.